# Word finder using regex patterns from a list of words

Tags: regex

I am have been trying to construct the regex for finding the words that contain specific characters similar to https://wordfinder.yourdictionary.com. So, this means if you have the following text https://regexr.com/54fju, and you want to search for 'abc' in the text than it should match the first 8 words but not the rest. Similarly, if you want to search for 'aab' then only the following words should be matched:- a, b, aab, aba, baa, aa, ab, ba. I have tried multiple patterns but nothing seems to work.

Can someone please help me with this or even tell me if it's even possible using regex as the list of words is very long and I don't want to programmatically go through the entire list with compare statements(my current plan).

Regards.

Comment: If you want a regex approach, you may try `^(?!.*(.).*\1)[abc]{1,3}$`, but it assumes all chars can only appear once. It is not the best idea to use a regex for this task.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is really a helpful solution thanks for the help. I am also not sure if this is even possible via regex but thought that it probably be fastest and cleaner and other methods.